# How can I add a value to a WTForms Submit field without changing its display label?

Tags: python, flask-wtforms

When I set a value for the field it changes the display label of the field. I'm using FlaskWTForms and the field is defined as:

```
class EditMultilpeChoiceQuestion(FlaskForm):

    submit_update = SubmitField(name="submit_update", label="Update question")
```

In the Jinja template the code to display the field is:

```
{{ form.submit_update(class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value=question['database_id']) }}
```

Is this example the value of question['database_id'] is 10 and the field display as:

[button display with value parameter added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVA6Y.png)

If I don't have the value=question['database_id'] the field displays as I want:

[button display with no value parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ7Lf.png)

any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: What behaviour of `value` do you expect from `SubmitField`?

Comment: I was hoping to be able to achieve the same thing using wtforms as with the original html I was using : 
`<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" name="update" type="submit" value="{{ question['database_id'] }}">Update the question</button>` 

and then read the value using something like
`quest['database_id'] = request.form.get('submit_update')`

Comment: This feels (to my limited HTML knowledge) like a bit of a hack.  The natural approach to me is to use a hidden field, just like you figured out after @pjcunningham's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widget used to render a submit field is a `SubmitInput`, [Github source](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/src/wtforms/widgets/core.py#L278), as shown below:

```
class SubmitInput(Input):
    """
    Renders a submit button.

    The field's label is used as the text of the submit button instead of the
    data on the field.
    """

    input_type = "submit"

    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault("value", field.label.text)
        return super().__call__(field, **kwargs)
```

Note the comment:

> The field's label is used as the text of the submit button instead of
> the data on the field.

See simple test code below:

```
from wtforms.fields import SubmitField
from wtforms.form import Form


class F(Form):
    a = SubmitField(label="Update question")


def test_submit_field():
    # Pass no args
    _html = F().a()
    print(_html)
    assert _html == """<input id="a" name="a" type="submit" value="Update question">"""

    # assigning the value clears the label
    _html = F().a(value=10)
    print(_html)
    assert _html == """<input id="a" name="a" type="submit" value="10">"""

    # assign label and value
    _html = F().a(label="Hello World", value=10)
    print(_html)
    assert _html == """<input id="a" label="Hello World" name="a" type="submit" value="10">"""


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_submit_field()
```

Comment: - thanks for the detailed reply. So basically it looks like what I was trying can never work.  I'll convert my form to use a hidden field and change the code where I read the value to look for that field instead of the submit field.